# Grouting wet outside of showers

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, leak, tiling

[image: Main shower leak][image: Guest shower leak]
We've recently installed two new bathrooms.

The showers in both bathrooms seem to have leaks in the exact same places, outside he left corner.

We're in this new house a month and now I'm starting to panic, about this little bit of water after every shower.

Opinions welcome, my plumber returns this week. See attached pics.

Comment: I really can't see much, is there a seal or bead of calking inside the shower on the frame to the to the tile? If coming from under the door I have needed to add drip ledges in the past so the water running down the door did not drip into the frame and leak to the outside.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for your comment. There is calking on the inside,but maybe it wasn't done correctly? I'm very annoyed :(

Comment: Get clear pictures and show them to your plumber.

Comment: I agree with Machavity. However, was the grout sealed? I don't see why the framing of the entryway was finished in grout. Usually a good watertight sealer is placed here finished with a bead of silicone.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you have tile all the way down, and a fiberglass pan. Even if the door was caulked properly, it's entirely possible that the water is wicking through the grout.

1. Make sure the entire door is caulked
2. Make sure the place where the tile meets the fiberglass is caulked as well

If either of these are not caulked, go buy a siliconized latex caulk and caulk it again yourself (make SURE it's dry first)